# Checked exceptions in Java when calling Groovy code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

When I have a Groovy class (in the groovy folder and ending in .groovy):

```
...
DerbyNow() throws IOException {
    // create socket connection
    socket = new EventSocket(new Socket(DERBY_NOW_HOST, DERBY_NOW_PORT)) // EventSocket throws IOException as well
    ...
```

and create it from Java code (in the java folder and ending in .java):

```
try {
    DerbyNow derbyNow = new DerbyNow();

    setDerbyNow(derbyNow);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.bad("error while setting up Derby Now: ", e);
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't give me an error/warning (correct), but when I go to compile/run, it gives me an error in the Messages Make view (incorrect):

```
Error:(382, 19) java: exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

How can I get it so that the compiler recognizes this exception? I looked at the decompiled groovy class (decompiled to Java), and it does still throw the `IOException`.

Here's part of my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

...

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    ...
}

...

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    ...
}
```

I am using the `javac` compiler (default).

Comment: Dumb downvote..I will upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had a clear answer from a Groovy specialist.
I had a similar issue and worked around it in a very ugly way:

```
try {
    DerbyNow derbyNow = new DerbyNow();

    setDerbyNow(derbyNow);
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceOf IOException) {
        Log.bad("error while setting up Derby Now: ", e);
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

So that works because since Java7, there is some special forgiveness for *Exception*.